# Shifting column titles to right

Tags: linux, sed, title, shift

I have a file which I want to process it in bash or python.
The structure is with 4 columns but only with 3 column titles:

```
input.txt

1STCOLUMN   2NDCOLUMN   THIRDCOLUMN
input1         12             33             45
input22        10             13              9
input4          2             23             11
input4534       3              1              1
```

I am trying to shift the title columns to right and add a title of `"INPUTS"` to the first column (input column).

Desired output: Adding the column title

```
Desired-output-step1.csv

    INPUTS     1STCOLUMN     2NDCOLUMN    THIRDCOLUMN
    input1          12         33            45
    input22         10         13             9
    input4           2         23            11
    input4534        3          1             1
```

I tried with `sed`:

```
sed -i '1iINPUTS, 1STCOLUMN, 2NDCOLUMN, THIRDCOLUMN' input.txt
```

But I do not prefer to type the names of the columns for this reason.

How do I just insert the new title to first column and the other column titles shift to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify which line to be replaced using line numbers

```
$ sed '1s/^/INPUTS       /' ip.txt
INPUTS       1STCOLUMN   2NDCOLUMN   THIRDCOLUMN
input1         12             33             45
input22        10             13              9
input4          2             23             11
input4534       3              1              1
```

- here, `1` indicates that you want to apply `s` command only for 1st line
- `s/^/INPUTS       /` insert something to start of line, you'll have to adjust the spacing as needed

Answer (score 1):

instead of counting and testing the spaces, you can let `column -t` do the padding and formatting job:

```
sed '1s/^/INPUTS /' ip.txt|column -t
```

This will give you:

```
INPUTS     1STCOLUMN  2NDCOLUMN  THIRDCOLUMN
input1     12         33         45
input22    10         13         9
input4     2          23         11
input4534  3          1          1
```